# 4G USB Dongle as Secondary WAN on Router

Tags: networking, router, usb, wireless-router

I have a router that has two WAN ports. The first is connected to my ISP router acting in Modem Mode only. Works perfectly.

I also have a USB dongle device that can act as a MiFi device or when directly attached to my laptop, as a 4G Dongle.

The other day we suffered an ISP outage whilst my wife was doing some work at home. She wasn't able to get on the Internet, so I let her use the USB dongle, but that meant only she could get on the Internet.

That got me thinking if there was a way I could use this USB dongle as the second WAN on my router.

I figured I'd need something to "interface" the two devices, so I found this: [TP-LINK TL-MR3020](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-LINK-TL-MR3020-Portable-Wireless-Router/dp/B00634PLTW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1480954304&sr=8-1&keywords=TP-LINK%20TL-MR3020) - a Portable router with an RJ45 socket and a USB socket for USB dongles.

From what I have read it appears this would work, but I'd have an additional NAT from that router to my main router.

How would I get the network working properly using this setup?

*NOTE: Suggestions for replacing the router are not what I am looking for, so thanks, but no thanks.*

Comment: We don't recommend hardware around here because your mileage may vary and hardware changes. The first question is good and I hope to see an answer. I've seen enterprise equipment that does exactly what you want, but would be interested if it can be hacked together with what you have. But the last part of your original question and your update will be off-topic due to their being specific hardware requests.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks and sorry for taking this off topic for the reasons you have stated. Unfortunately, I'm sure I already know how to do what you have changed the question to be, so I guess I need to delete it as it won't be of use to me as you have edited it. I wanted other users advice and that isn't allowed here. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, it's a sticky point. The main issue we don't do that sort of question is because the right answer today will not be the right answer tomorrow when it comes to hardware. SuperUser's goal is to be a place full of good answers with only the commentary and conversation necessary to make those answers good. Subjects whose answers are likely to go bad tomorrow are discouraged or disallowed for this reason.